# Adding JSF UIComponent as composite component child renders nothing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uicomponents, composite-component

I have a custom `UIComponent`, which renders ok when called directly from the base facelet template (I guess this makes it a direct child of `UIComponentBodyTag`). However, when it is called within a composite component, nothing happens. I get no exceptions, nothing. Everything else renders ok.

So while this works:

```
<h:body>
    <x:myUiComponent />
</h:body>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<h:body>
    <demo:uiComponentWrapper />
</h:body>
```

uiComponentWrapper.xhtml:

```
<cc:implementation>
    Before [<x:myUiComponent />] After
</cc:implementation>
```

It prints simply as `Before [] After`.

By my logic, this should work. What am I missing? Running Mojarra 2.0.2.

Comment: No replies so far, so I conclude this might be a bug or configuration error. Any suggestions still welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `UIComponent`'s `encodeAll(...)` is called when it is added to page normally. However, `encodeBegin(...)` is called instead, when component is being added as a child of a composite component. My component building was defined in `encodeAll(...)`, which wasn't run when adding the component as a composite component child.

So it's just different in different contexts. For the reason, why it is so, see [question about exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284060/jsf-2-0-when-is-encodeall-called-and-when-is-encodebegin-called).